# Nopcommerce view not updating

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nopcommerce

I updated the view `CategoryTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines` in NopCommerce source code and also added custom code in CatalogController > Category action.

The breakpoints are hitting in the controller code but the View breakpoints are disabled. It says a copy for the view is found and source code is newer.

The controller is sending the updated data but the view is not rendering it the way I want. I also tried adding the random string on the view and it is still not showing that string on the page or in its source code in the browser.

I cleaned and rebuilt the solution. I cleaned the NopCommerce cache. I published it to Azure and restarted the app. But still, the new view updates are not visible. What should I do?

**UPDATE**

Looks like there is some problem with NopCommerce caching system. I returned the view by mentioning the View file path directly and it worked. I tried clearing NopCommerce cache from admin but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you checking on Azure? what about local machine? does it works there?

Comment: @div same result on both local and azure app.

Comment: Okay, which version of nope are you using? and this smell like browser cache instead nopCommerce cache.

Comment: @Div 4.10 and cleared everything. Even removed ASP.NET temporary files. Tried on other browsers also.

Comment: Okay, could you share your code to public repo? If possible! I'll take a look.

Comment: @Div I haven't changed anything in the NopCommerce code. The code is original as given on Nop commerce repository here: https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/develop/src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Views/Catalog/CategoryTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines.cshtml 

I just added some content in view. Even tried adding just Random string `ABCD` just before product list.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I will check and let me know

Comment: Checked with nop 4.1 default code, couldn't able to generate the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pccw4.gif Make sure you're not referring the wrong view page, as there are multiple if you're using a theme.

Comment: @div Oh yes.. my bad. I was editing the actual page, not the theme page. When I found the theme page and made the changes there, it worked. Thank you so much. Please add it as an answer so that I can award the bounty.

Comment: Glad your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While working view pages in nopCommerce, bear in mind, there are multiple places from view pages being served; inside plugin (if you'd have override any), default view pages and theme pages.

Default nopCommerce code uses view pages from root folder(i.e. from `Views` folder); however, if you've enabled the theme, it will use pages from theme folder. So, make sure you're referring right pages.